# How to express XML with mixed content using Jackson XmlMapper

Tags: java, xml, jackson-dataformat-xml

I need write a Java program that will generate a XML with mixed content. It should more or less like this:

```
   <foo>
       <bar><a></a>Some text<b></b></bar>
    </foo>
```

I would like to use Jackson  XML Mapper to serialize Java objects to XML but I don't know how to build an object equivalent to above XML.

Comment: I don't know whether it's possible, but I would suggest it isn't a good idea. Data binding technologies like Jackson are usually pretty bad at handling mixed content. Much better to write the XML directly using, for example, an XMLStreamWriter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I was able to generated expected XML using following Java record:

```
record foo(
        @JacksonXmlProperty
        Bar bar
){};

@JsonPropertyOrder({"a", "content", "b"})
record Bar(
        @JsonInclude
        @JacksonXmlProperty
        String a,
        @JacksonXmlText
        String content,
        @JsonInclude
        @JacksonXmlProperty
        String b
) {
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done with Jackson as per its [known limitations](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml#known-limitations). But this can be done with `JAXB` by declaring the contents of the `bar` field/class as `@XmlMixed`. You can find the code below:

**Gradle dependencies:**

```
implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'
implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '2.3.1'
```

**Foo.java:**

```java
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@Setter
@XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
public class Foo {
    @XmlElement
    private Bar bar;
}
```

**Bar.java:**

```java
import lombok.Setter;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlMixed;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

@Setter
public class Bar {
    @XmlMixed
    private List<Serializable> content;
}
```

**XML Serialization code:**

```java
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

// ...Class and method declaration omitted

List<Serializable> content = new ArrayList<>();
content.add(new JAXBElement(new QName("a"), String.class, "value-a"));
content.add("Some text");
content.add(new JAXBElement(new QName("b"), String.class, "value-b"));
Bar bar = new Bar();
bar.setContent(content);
Foo foo = new Foo();
foo.setBar(bar);

StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class, Bar.class);
Marshaller marshaller = context.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FRAGMENT, true);
marshaller.marshal(foo, writer);
String xmlString = writer.toString();
```

The XML generated by the above code will look like the below:

```xml
<foo><bar><a>value-a</a>Some text<b>value-b</b></bar></foo>
```

You can find the complete working sample on [github](https://github.com/devatherock/java-demo/commit/31f9f186c98ab327640426582c5e1f61dc785a49).